# How to make span button appear when mouseover a b tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use ajaxsumit to upload file to linux server successfully.

When uploading file was done, the file name and size would  appear in my website with a cancelfile button.

But when mouse over the file name, the cancelfile button can not appear. I don't know why ? who can help me ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#filename').mouseover(function(){
        $('#cnlbtn').css("display","block");
    });
    $('#filename').mouseout(function(){
        $('#cnlbtn').css("display","none");
    });
});

$("#fileupload").change(function(){
    $("#myupload").ajaxSubmit({
        dataType:  'json',
        beforeSend: function() {},
        uploadProgress: function() {},
        success: function(data) {
            files.html("<br />"+"<b id='filename'>"+data.name+"("+data.size+"k)</b> <span class='delimg' rel='"+data.pic+"' id='cnlbtn'>cancelfile</span>");
            btn.html("addfile");
        },
        error:function(xhr){}
        });
```

My delimg style:

```
   .delimg{margin-left:20px; color:#090; cursor:pointer;display:none}
```

Comment: Would event delegation work in this case? For example: `$(document).on("mouseover", "#filename", function(){ ///do something });`

Answer (score 0):

Is not working because when you add the event listener the tag does not exist yet in the DOM. As Joe B. said you need to use event delegation: [jQuery Doc Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

So you have to do something like this:

```
$(document.body).on('mouseover', '#filename', function(){
    $('#cnlbtn').css("display","block");
});
$(document.body).on('mouseout', '#filename', function(){
    $('#cnlbtn').css("display","none");
});
```